# Rastor Image just showing image path

Tags: c#, autocad

I am trying to add an image to a CAD drawing but just get a rectangle with the path shown and no image displayed.

Can I not add images to Paper Space or only particular types of images that can be added to paper space (adding a .jpg type in my case). Here is my code.

```
private void AddLogoImage(Transaction trans, BlockTableRecord titleRecord)
    { 
        // Define the name and image to use
        string imageName = "Comp Logo";
        string fileName = @"C:\Autodesk\Image\comp_logo.jpg";

        RasterImageDef imageDef;
        ObjectId imageDefId;

        // Get the image dictionary
        ObjectId imageDictId = RasterImageDef.GetImageDictionary(titleRecord.Database);

        // Check to see if the dictionary does not exist, it not then create it
        if (imageDictId.IsNull)
        {
            imageDictId = RasterImageDef.CreateImageDictionary(titleRecord.Database);
        }

        // Open the image dictionary
        DBDictionary imageDict = trans.GetObject(imageDictId, OpenMode.ForRead) as DBDictionary;

        // Check to see if the image definition already exists
        if (imageDict.Contains(imageName))
        {
            imageDefId = imageDict.GetAt(imageName);
            imageDef = trans.GetObject(imageDefId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as RasterImageDef;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a raster image definition
            RasterImageDef newImageDef = new RasterImageDef();

            // Set the source for the image file
            newImageDef.SourceFileName = fileName;

            // Load the image into memory
            newImageDef.Load();

            // Add the image definition to the dictionary
            imageDict.UpgradeOpen();
            imageDefId = imageDict.SetAt(imageName, newImageDef);
            trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(newImageDef, true);
            imageDef = newImageDef;
        }

        // Create the new image and assign it the image definition
        using (RasterImage acRaster = new RasterImage())
        {
            acRaster.ImageDefId = imageDefId;

            Vector3d width;
            Vector3d height;

            // Check to see if the measurement is set to English (Imperial) or Metric units
            if (titleRecord.Database.Measurement == MeasurementValue.English)
            {
                width = new Vector3d((imageDef.ResolutionMMPerPixel.X * acRaster.ImageWidth) / 25.4, 0, 0);
                height = new Vector3d(0, (imageDef.ResolutionMMPerPixel.Y * acRaster.ImageHeight) / 25.4, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                width = new Vector3d(imageDef.ResolutionMMPerPixel.X * acRaster.ImageWidth, 0, 0);
                height = new Vector3d(0, imageDef.ResolutionMMPerPixel.Y * acRaster.ImageHeight, 0);
            }

            // Define the position for the image 
            Point3d insPt = new Point3d(720, 129, 0.0);

            // Define and assign a coordinate system for the image's orientation
            CoordinateSystem3d coordinateSystem = new CoordinateSystem3d(insPt, width * 2, height * 2);
            acRaster.Orientation = coordinateSystem;

            // Set the rotation angle for the image
            acRaster.Rotation = 0;

            // Add the new object to the block table record and the transaction
            titleRecord.AppendEntity(acRaster);
            trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acRaster, true);

            // Connect the raster definition and image together so the definition
            // does not appear as "unreferenced" in the External References palette.
            RasterImage.EnableReactors(true);
            acRaster.AssociateRasterDef(imageDef);
            imageDef.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Should I not be using Rastor Images and if not is there an alternative?

Shows correctly in PDF from dwg file, although prefer to have no rectangular border.

Answer (score 0):

To show no border you can set the color property of the image to rgb(255,255,255), assuming it is a white background you are working with

Comment: that solves the border but still doesn't display the image in Paper Space

Answer (score 0):

The free TrueView free DWG viewer doesn't show the image. The image is successfully created and visible in full version of AutoDesk AutoCAD